# Module which modifies the module that imports it

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to write a module `magic.py` such that the following code

```
import magic

def foo():
    print "hello"
```

invokes the function `foo` after its declaration, i.e. prints `hello`?

Comment: Can't call a function that wasn't declared yet, so no. You can however, hook functions from other modules, as long as they've already been loaded of course, for the same reason.

Comment: I guess you could trigger that with a timed event though.

Comment: no "magic" needed, assuming your code is in script `my_module.py`, `magic.py` containing `from my_module import foo; foo()` does that

Answer (score 0):

no "magic" needed,
`my_module.py`:

```
your code
```

`magic.py`:

```
my_module import foo
foo()
```

prints: `hello`